# Zapier Code FETCH POST action doesn't include body

Tags: zapier

I'm using Zaper's Code by Zapier to make an HTTP POST, but it appears the body is empty. I've checked [Zapier's docs](https://zapier.com/help/code/) and [Node-Fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/tree/32b60634434a63865ea3f79edb33d17e40876c9f#usage), and it looks like my syntax is correct, yet when I inspect the request there appears to not be a body.

```
var testendpoint = 'http://example.com';
var payload = {
  'data':  [
    {
      'Date':  'dateparsed',
      'Signups':  '1'
    }
  ],
  'color':  {
    'Signups':  '#2fd75b'
  }
};

fetch(testendpoint, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(responsebody) {
    var output = {response: responsebody};
    callback(null, output);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    callback(error);
  });
```

Comment: I'm suffering the exact same issue, with very similar code. The body of the request is simply not being sent. I've contacted Zapier support, I'll post any response here.

Answer (score 1):

After suffering the exact same issue, I got word back from Zapier Support that the issue was able to be replicated and we have indeed found a bug. They're looking into it and will notify me when fixed. I'll post here when that happens.

**Update 30/10:** The issue was with the version of Node.js being used - They've now updated and I can confirm that the payload is now being sent with requests. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely looks like the correct code to me.

Have you tried making `var testendpoint = 'http://requestb.in/12qc4a11';` or something using the wonderful http://requestb.in/ service?

Comment: Yes, requestbin indicates there's no data. If you have a working sample text, I'd love to hack a working model!